# PopUp to open a link and close itself

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a popup that offers a visitor the choice of two links. If either one of the links is clicked on, I would like for (1) the popup to close itself and (2) the selected link to open in a new window. What occurs now when one of the two offered links is chosen is (1) the popup closes itself and (2) an empty new window opens. How can I get the selected link to display in the new window? 
Thank you.

Here is the code I have written:

In the main window's HEAD:

```
    function OpenQuick() 
    {
    var windowcontents = "https://myurl.com/quicklink.html";
    var win =window.open(windowcontents,"remote",'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=450,height=425');
win.creator=self;
myWindow.focus();
}
```

In the Body of the main window:

```
    <a href="javascript:OpenQuick();"><img src="https://www.myurl.com/images/link.gif"></a>
```

In the POPUP:

```
    <a href="choiceone.html" target="_blank" onclick="self.close();">First Choice</a>
    <a href="choicetwo.html" target="_blank" onclick="self.close();">Second Choice</a>
```

Comment: This is tricky. I wonder if it would work better this way - give the target a real name, like target="mynewquickielink" or something. Not an _xxx target value. Still in the popup, the onclick should be "newRoutine();" You don't have to have javascript: any more. Then in newRoutine() you can call self.close() after a delay using setTimeout. I'm thinking things are going too fast and you want to close a bit later. Might help!

Comment: Thank you. First, I need to say that while I have a pretty good sense of HTML, I am really new to writing Javascript. I do not recognize "newRoutine()" so I could not figure out how to place it, but following part of your suggestion, here is what I have written into the popup: <a href="choiceone.html" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setTimeout (window.close, 5000);">
revision one</a>  It works perfectly on a Mac OS10.15 in Firefox and Internet Explorer, and on Windows10 in Firefox and Chrome. BUT on Windows, Internet Explorer opens the link in the popup rather than in a new blank window.

Comment: You suggested giving the target a real name like target="mynewquickielink"  That may solve the Windows issue in Internet Explorer, so I would like to use it. But if I made the target that, how would I then specify that "mynewquickielink" is actually a new blank window?

Comment: Oops! I should have said:  It works perfectly on a Mac OS10.15 in Firefox and Safari (not Internet Explorer), and on Windows10 in Firefox and Chrome. BUT on Windows, Internet Explorer (now called Edge?) opens the link in the popup rather than in a new blank window.

Comment: The latest Internet Explorer is 11, released in about 2013. It's still out there, unrenamed. There is an Edge as well, in two flavors, the later one being webkit based. It's up to you if you want to support IE11, of course. In my work, we have what I believe to be the lowest tech savviness of any user base in a 1st world country (and probably lower than most 2nd and 3rd world countries!) and we have dropped IE11 support some time ago.  But I digress.

Comment: Francis - ANY name given in target="" causes a new window (or tab) unless that name is already in use, in which case it re-uses the existing window/tab with that name.

Comment: finally - newRoutine() is something you made up and wrote. It's a function that does what I said - calls open quick, waits a little, then does the close - function newRoutine () { setTimeout( function () { self.close() }, 1000) } -- or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help. I don't propose any change to OpenQuick():

```js
function OpenQuick() {
  var windowcontents = "https://myurl.com/quicklink.html";
  var win=window.open( windowcontents, "remote", "(whatever)");
  win.creator=self;
  myWindow.focus();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="OpenQuick();"><img src="(someimage)"></a>
```

In new / popup -

```html
    <a href="choiceone.html" target="anyname" onclick="newRoutine();">Choice1</a>
    <a href="choicetwo.html" target="anyname" onclick="newRoutine();">Choice2</a>
```

With javascript definition of the newRoutine on that popup -

```js
function newRoutine () {
  setTimeout( function () { self.close(); }, 1000); // 1000 is in ms = 1s
}
```

The idea being to give the popup a bit of time before trying the close.

Answer (score 0):

Yishmeray, You wrote, "In case this might help"! Not only did it help, your solution answered my question and solved my problem! 
    I urge anyone who has a similar issue to try adapting Yishmeray's suggestion to their situation. It's simple, it's easy to understand, and it works! 
    Yishmeray, thank you.